# Handling cronjobs in a MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cron

At work we've developed our own MVC framework which provides us with as many as possible automated code-generation/handling. A few minutes ago I was talking with my collegue about how to handle cronjobs via a(ny) framework.

Basically we have cronjobs for:

1. Mailing purposes
2. Update procedures
3. Garbage collection

What is your opinion/vision/best-practise on how to set up cronjobs? 
Is a cronjob just a PHP file using some controllers which use models to perform their tasks, or should a class be created for this?

In our opinion a cronjob is a procedure which needs controllers to do their work. What's your opinion?

Comment: You framework should run in different environments so you can call it from the command line for CRON etc and from the web. Your controllers will just call different views depending on the environment.

Comment: That's no problem. So you say a cronjob is a PHP file, using the MVC, calling/using controllers to do the task and not have a cronjob-class? (Just collecting ideas and perspectives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've followed best design practice and coded all your business logic into your models, all you need is a new controller that can process commandline input and a simple view that just outputs the results to STDOUT.

You did put all your business logic in your models, right?  Cos if there's a lot of it in the controllers then you're in trouble ;)